# Can I override laravel 5.6 validation?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I am trying to add condition based validation. I have a  detect function which is responsible for detecting that input is email or a number

```
$detectInput = $this->EmailService->detectInput($request->email);
```

So `$detectInput` always returns `0` or `1` or `2`

```
$messages = [
    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
    'unique' => 'The :attribute already exists.',
    'email' => 'The :attribute is invalid',
];

$rules = [
    'email'     => 'required|string',
];


    $detectInput = $this->EmailService->detectInput($request->email);
    if ($detectInput===1 || $detectInput===0) {
        $rules =  array_set($rules, 'email', 'email|unique:users');
    }

    if ($detectInput===2) {
        $rules =  array_set($rules, 'email', 'unique:users,login_number');
    }

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
```

The first `if-statement` is working fine, but I am not able to override when second `if-statement` get true. I want to override validation that check the input from `users.login_number` columns value, where value is duplicated or no instead of `users.email`.

can someone kindly guide me about it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: $detectInput will have one of three values 0,1,2 or there can be any two as well ?

Comment: Can you confirm that you're definitely able to get `2` not ("2") returned from `detectInput()`?

Comment: @Rwd yes exactly it would be integer `2`

Comment: Ok, so you've submitted a number instead of an email, it's returning `2` and the second if statement condition is passing? Please can you add the following underneath the second if statement and show the output in your question: `dd($rules, $request->all());`